# JQuery - how to add a button to an column from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I want to add a button to the column Action but I cant put the value of `data-activateUser= item["AspNetUserId"]`. I am jusing a plugin DataTables btw.

**My Table**

[image]

**DataSource**

```
$.getJSON("/Account/InactiveAccounts").then(function (items) {
                var item = items;
                console.log(item["UserAccounts"]);
                $('#inactive-accounts').DataTable({
                    columnDefs: [{ targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false }],
                    data: item["UserAccounts"],
                    "processing": true,
                    columns: [
                        { data: "Username" },
                        { data: "Password" },
                        { data: "Email" },
                        {
                            data: function () {
                                return `<button onclick="clickDeactivateUser(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-activateUser=`+ item["AspNetUserId"] +`>Activate</button>
                                            `;
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                });
```

**JSON Data**

[image]

Comment: Did your button successfully created or doesn't shown up? I think you need to use `render` function instead of assigning data directly to `data` property; see [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/47910/add-button-column) to add button column.

Comment: it successfully created

Comment: but when I try to get the `data-activateUser` from the button it gives me undefined error

Comment: Did you use `$(this).data('activateUser')` somewhere and returns undefined? Are you unable to put the attribute into button element, or get the value from that attribute which exist in button after rendering?

Comment: You just missed the double quotes... ``data-activateUser=`+ item["AspNetUserId"] +`>`` should be ``data-activateUser="`+ item["AspNetUserId"] +`">`` - **I'm voting to close as a typo.**

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks sir. the undifined error was gone but it seems that the item["AspNetUserId"] is null

Comment: I messed up my json when I try this `data-activateuser="` + item['UserAccounts']['0'].AspNetUserId +`"`

Comment: but the problem is I am having the same `AspNetUserId` because it only access the `Index 0` from the `JSON` how do I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your

```
data: function () {
    return `<button onclick="clickDeactivateUser(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-activateUser=`+ item["AspNetUserId"] +`>Activate</button>`;
}
```

to

```
render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<button onclick="clickDeactivateUser(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-activateUser="'+ row.AspNetUserId +'">Activate</button>';
}
```

For further details about renderers, please check [this](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers)

Comment: thanks sir it works, I think just got confused with the json array, please consider to undo the downvote sir thanks.